# How To Count Time in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, time

I have two variable:

```
start = "14:00"
duration = "30" (minutes"
```

How to counting the time with Jquery or Javascript? So it's look like `14:00 + 30 = 14:30`

Comment: what did you try towards this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use moment.js

http://momentjs.com/

Its a perfect plugin for alle date manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer all the values into seconds and then make them HH:MM

```
start = "14:00" => 14*60*60 translates to seconds
duration = "30" = > 30*60 translates to seconds

var theDate = (new Date).clearTime().addSeconds(57600).toString('H:mm:ss');
```

:)

[date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: but can you tell me the clear code. because i'm using the dynamic data. the start source is $("#timepicker1") and duration source is $("dura")

Comment: In the timepicker how do you add the time? With jQuery ui datepicker or similar?

Comment: hi Bojan, i'm using Moment.js and it work perfectly. you must try! :D